# Where is NDK Directory Location on Windows

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've downloaded Android NDK from https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html
According to the documentation, I've to double click the NDK download and it will automatically extract file. I ran and now I don't know where it has extracted the files. Do people have any idea where can I find the Android NDK directory?

Answer (score 1):

Found the directory. As I've downloaded 64 bit NDK, it's

```
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\android-ndk-r10e"
```

on my 64bit Windows 7 machine.

I used this command from DOS Command Prompt to find the directory:

```
dir /b /s /ad | findstr "android-ndk-r10e"
```